# npm install installing extra packages not specified in package.json

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a fairly typical `package.json` on an AWS ec2 instance. I'm running `npm install` and instead of installing

```
{
  "name": "angular-app-server",
  "description": "Back end server to support our angular app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "assert": "^1.3.0",
    "async": "^0.9.0",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.13.1",
    "connect-multiparty": "^1.2.5",
    "express": "~3.0",
    "express-namespace": "~0.1.1",
    "express-session": "^1.11.1",
    "forever": "^0.14.2",
    "mongodb": "^2.0.36",
    "multiparty": "^4.1.2",
    "nodemailer": "^1.3.4",
    "open": "0.0.3",
    "passport": "~0.1.12",
    "passport-local": "~0.1.6",
    "request": "~2.16.6",
    "svgo": "^0.5.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-nodeunit": "~0.1.2",
    "rewire": "^2.0.1",
    "supervisor": "~0.4.1"
  }
}
```

It's installing dozens and dozens of packages, (via `cd node_modules` & `ls`):

```
abbrev                findup-sync                  on-finished
addressparser         first-chunk-stream           on-headers
align-text            flatiron                     open
amdefine              foreground-child             opener
ansi-regex            forever                      optimist
ansi-styles           forever-agent                optionator
argparse              forever-monitor              parseurl
asn1                  form-data                    passport
assert                formidable                   passport-local
assert-plus           fresh                        path-is-absolute
async                 getobject                    pause
aws-sign              glob                         peakle
aws-sign2             graceful-fs                  pend
balanced-match        grunt                        pkginfo
base64-url            grunt-contrib-jshint         prelude-ls
bcrypt-nodejs         grunt-contrib-nodeunit       prompt
body-parser           grunt-legacy-log             ps-tree
boom                  grunt-legacy-log-utils       punycode
brace-expansion       grunt-legacy-util            q
broadway              handlebars                   qs
bson                  has-ansi                     range-parser
buffer-crc32          hawk                         raw-body
buffer-equal          hoek                         read
buildmail             hooker                       readable-stream
bytes                 http-errors                  repeat-string
camelcase             http-signature               request
center-align          hyperquest                   resolve
chalk                 i                            revalidator
cli                   iconv-lite                   rewire
cliff                 inflight                     right-align
cliui                 inherits                     rimraf
clone                 ini                          sax
coa                   isarray                      send
coffee-script         isstream                     shelljs
colors                istanbul                     sigmund
combined-stream       is-utf8                      signal-exit
commander             jshint                       smtp-connection
concat-map            json-stringify-safe          sntp
connect               js-yaml                      source-map
connect-multiparty    kerberos                     spawn-wrap
content-type          kind-of                      sprintf-js
cookie                lazy                         stack-trace
cookie-jar            lcov-parse                   statuses
cookie-signature      levn                         stream-counter
core-util-is          libbase64                    string_decoder
coveralls             libmime                      stringstream
crc                   libqp                        strip-ansi
cryptiles             lodash                       strip-bom
ctype                 log-driver                   supervisor
cycle                 longest                      supports-color
dateformat            lru-cache                    svgo
debug                 media-typer                  tap
decamelize            methods                      tap-mocha-reporter
deep-equal            mime                         tap-parser
deep-is               mime-db                      through2
delayed-stream        mime-types                   timespan
depd                  minimatch                    tough-cookie
diff                  minimist                     tunnel-agent
director              mkdirp                       type-check
duplexer2             mongodb                      type-is
ee-first              mongodb-core                 uglify-js
es6-promise           ms                           uid-safe
escape-string-regexp  multiparty                   underscore
escodegen             mute-stream                  underscore.string
esprima               nan                          unicode-length
estraverse            nconf                        unpipe
esutils               ncp                          util
eventemitter2         nodemailer                   utile
events-to-array       nodemailer-direct-transport  utils-merge
event-stream          nodemailer-smtp-transport    watch
exit                  nodemailer-wellknown         whet.extend
express               nodeunit                     which
express-namespace     node-uuid                    window-size
express-session       nopt                         winston
eyes                  nssocket                     wordwrap
fast-levenshtein      nyc                          wrappy
fd-slicer             oauth-sign                   xtend
fileset               once                         yargs
```

What could be the cause of this?

Thanks for any advice or help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a difference between NPM 2 and NPM 3.
NPM 3 will put the first version of a dependency as a peer and other versions of a dependency nested.

- https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3
- https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11586

I guess it looks uglier, but takes less space.

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks for the info :-)

Answer (score 3):

They are dependencies of the modules you want. This can't be avoided.

Comment: I don't believe this is true, as it should nest dependencies of each respective module in that module's own ```node_modules``` folder. Each ```node_modules``` folder should only have the modules listed in ```package.json```

Comment: This is probably true. There may be something else going on on the user's system that was flattening the packages. Npm 3 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm3) tries to install packages in a maximally flat way to make it easier for Windows users. There are other utilities that can be run to do move the package folders after an npm install like flatten-packages (https://www.npmjs.com/package/flatten-packages).

Comment: My point earlier is that those packages must be installed (somewhere) for the packages in packages.json to be installed.

Comment: Interesting. It's on a fresh linux ec2 instance with a ```package.json``` that I wrote myself so I'm not sure where the behavior would come from. I did install the latest npm, so maybe npm is doing it by default for some reason. Also weird that you wouldn't run into versioning issues with such a structure.