# npm installing almost 200 libraries by default

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm very new to npm and so this might be something simple but I haven't found any mention of it anywhere. Maybe it's just a config mistake.

I'm slowly getting into npm and task automation, currently following [this tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/) (CSS-Tricks) to learn the basics of gulp.

When I execute the command `npm install gulp --save-dev` I get a very different result than what's in the tutorial. After installing gulp, my project's `node_modules` folder contains 196 folders:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                .bin
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                ansi-regex
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                ansi-styles
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                archy
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                arr-diff
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                arr-flatten
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                array-differ
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                array-find-index
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                array-uniq
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                array-unique
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                balanced-match
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                beeper
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                brace-expansion
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                braces
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                builtin-modules
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                camelcase
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                camelcase-keys
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                chalk
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                clone
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                clone-stats
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                concat-map
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                core-util-is
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                currently-unhandled
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                dateformat
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                decamelize
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                defaults
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                deprecated
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                detect-file
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                duplexer2
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                end-of-stream
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                error-ex
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                escape-string-regexp
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                expand-brackets
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                expand-range
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                expand-tilde
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                extend
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                extglob
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                fancy-log
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                filename-regex
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                fill-range
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                find-index
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                find-up
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                findup-sync
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                fined
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                first-chunk-stream
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                flagged-respawn
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                for-in
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                for-own
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                fs-exists-sync
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                gaze
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                get-stdin
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                glob
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                glob-base
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                glob-parent
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                glob-stream
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                glob-watcher
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                glob2base
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                global-modules
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                global-prefix
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                globule
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                glogg
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                graceful-fs
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                gulp
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                gulp-util
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                gulplog
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                has-ansi
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                has-gulplog
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                hosted-git-info
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                indent-string
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                inflight
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                inherits
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                ini
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                interpret
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                is-absolute
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                is-arrayish
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                is-buffer
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                is-builtin-module
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                is-dotfile
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                is-equal-shallow
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                is-extendable
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                is-extglob
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                is-finite
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                is-glob
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                is-number
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                is-posix-bracket
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                is-primitive
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                is-relative
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                is-unc-path
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                is-utf8
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                is-windows
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                isarray
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                isexe
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                isobject
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                kind-of
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                liftoff
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                load-json-file
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                lodash
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                lodash.assignwith
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                lodash.escape
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                lodash.isarguments
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                lodash.isarray
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                lodash.isempty
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                lodash.isplainobject
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                lodash.isstring
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                lodash.keys
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                lodash.mapvalues
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                lodash.pick
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                lodash.restparam
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                lodash.template
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                lodash.templatesettings
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                lodash._basecopy
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                lodash._basetostring
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                lodash._basevalues
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                lodash._getnative
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                lodash._isiterateecall
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                lodash._reescape
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                lodash._reevaluate
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                lodash._reinterpolate
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                lodash._root
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                loud-rejection
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                lru-cache
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                map-cache
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                map-obj
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                meow
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                micromatch
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                minimatch
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                minimist
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                mkdirp
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                multipipe
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                natives
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                normalize-package-data
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                normalize-path
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                number-is-nan
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                object-assign
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                object.omit
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                once
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                orchestrator
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                ordered-read-streams
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                os-homedir
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                os-tmpdir
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                osenv
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                parse-filepath
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                parse-glob
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                parse-json
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                path-exists
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                path-root
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                path-root-regex
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                path-type
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                pify
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                pinkie
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                pinkie-promise
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                preserve
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                pretty-hrtime
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                process-nextick-args
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                randomatic
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                read-pkg
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                read-pkg-up
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                readable-stream
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                rechoir
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                redent
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                regex-cache
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                repeat-element
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                repeat-string
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                repeating
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                replace-ext
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                resolve
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                resolve-dir
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                semver
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                sequencify
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                sigmund
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                signal-exit
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                sparkles
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                spdx-correct
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                spdx-expression-parse
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                spdx-license-ids
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                stream-consume
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                string_decoder
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                strip-ansi
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                strip-bom
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                strip-indent
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                supports-color
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                through2
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                tildify
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                time-stamp
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                trim-newlines
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                unc-path-regex
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                unique-stream
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                user-home
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                util-deprecate
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                v8flags
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                validate-npm-package-license
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                vinyl
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                vinyl-fs
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                which
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                wrappy
d-----       11/22/2016      4:40                xtend
```

Just to make sure it's not something I messed up before I reinstalled Node.js, the results were the same. I'm running Windows 10.

Is this supposed to happen? If not, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal. `npm` resolves the whole dependency tree of gulp which could be a lot. A dependency can contain dependencies which then contain other dependencies.

Also, `npm` installs this all as flat and no nesting: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9809, this is why you have a lot of files in your directory.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my Google-Fu is not what it used to be. I found a question about this [on this very page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31467505/npm-install-installing-extra-packages-not-specified-in-package-json).

Apparently this is how the newer versions of npm install dependancies by default and everything's fine, the tutorial was simply using an older version of npm.